# HTTP Response Properties Undefined

Tags: javascript, json, http

I am making a http request which gives me a large JSON response in Node. I am trying to access an array of objects within the response with the intention of getting down further to retrieve an array of objects. My current code is as follows:

```
let urlBase ='https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/seasons/2021/segments/0/leagues/72628823?view=mMatchup&view=mMatchupScore&scoringPeriodId=';
let url = urlBase.concat(week);
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get(url).then((res)=> 
{
   let allRosters = res.data.teams;
   let rosters = (allRosters) => {
       let pogBoys = [];
       for(let i in allRosters){
           pogBoys.push(i.roster);
           console.log(i.roster);
       }
       return pogBoys;
   };
   rosters(allRosters);
}    
);
```

The console.log within my for...in loop is returning undefined when I run it. I have checked the endpoint and there is data there so it should have something. Is there something that I need to do differently to access data from within my response?

Comment: `i` is the array index, not the array element.

Comment: Use `for (let i of allRosters)` to iterate over the array elements.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(i)`?

Comment: I changed it to of instead of in and that fixed my issue. I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array.map:
About: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
   axios.get(urlBase).then((res)=> {

        let allRosters = res.data.teams;

        let rosters = allRosters.map(item => item.roster)

        console.log(rosters)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to:

```
for (let i of allRosters)
```

Instead of:

```
for (let i in allRosters)
```

And that solved the issue per Barmar's advice.